# RGB to YIQ conversion

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I wrote code for rgb to yiq conversion.I get results but i don't know if this is correct.

```
%extract the red green blue elements 
ImageGridRed = double(ImageRGB(:,:,1))';
ImageGridGreen = double(ImageRGB(:,:,2))';
ImageGridBlue = double(ImageRGB(:,:,3))';    

%make the 300x300 matrices into 1x90000 matrices
flag = 1;

for i =1:1:300
for j = 1:1:300

imageGR(flag) = ImageGridRed(j,i);
imageGG(flag) = ImageGridGreen(j,i);
imageGB(flag) = ImageGridBlue(j,i);

flag = flag+1;

end
end

%put the 3 matrices into 1 matrix 90000x3
for j=1:1:300*300

colorRGB(j,1) = imageGR(j);
colorRGB(j,2) = imageGG(j);
colorRGB(j,3) = imageGB(j);

end

YIQ = rgb2ntsc([colorRGB(:,1) colorRGB(:,2) colorRGB(:,3)]);
```

I wrote this because the rgb2ntsc function needs mx3 matrix for input.I use the number 300 beacuse the picture is 300x300 pixels.I am going to seperate the picture in blocks in my project so dont give attention to the 300 number because i am going to change that, i put it just as an example.

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing is completely unnecessary.  If you consult [the documentation on `rgb2ntsc`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/rgb2ntsc.html), it also **accepts a RGB image**.  Therefore, when you put in a RGB image, the output will be a 3 channel image, where the first channel is the luminance, or `Y` component and the second and third channels are the hue and saturation information (`I` and `Q` respectively).  You don't need to decompose the image into a `M x 3` matrix.

Therefore, simply do:

```
YIQ = rgb2ntsc(ImageRGB);
```

Make sure that `ImageRGB` is a RGB image where the first channel is red, second is green and third is blue.

---

## Edit

With your comments, you want to take all of the pixels and place it into a `M x 3` matrix where `M` is the total number of pixels.  You would use this as input into `rgb2ntsc`.  The function accepts a `M x 3` matrix of RGB values where each row is a RGB tuple.  The output in this case will be another `M x 3` matrix where each row is its YIQ counterpart.  Your code does do what you want it to do, but I would recommend that you do away with the `for` loops and replace it with:

```
colorRGB = reshape(permute(ImageRGB, [3 1 2]), 3, []).';,
```

After, do `YIQ = rgb2ntsc(colorRGB);`. `colorRGB` will already be a M x 3 matrix, so that column indexing you're doing is superfluous.

With the above using `reshape` and `permute`, it's very unnecessary to use the loops.  In fact, I would argue that the `for` loop code is slower.  Stick with the above code to get this done fast.  Once you have your matrix in this fashion, then I suppose the code is doing what you want it to do.... however, I would personally just do a conversion on the image itself, then split it up into blocks or whatever you want to do after the fact.

Comment: i am going to separate the image into blocks and i want to transport every block into YIQ  thats why i did this.

Comment: Each pixel can be converted **independently** into YIQ.  RGB to YIQ is simply a weighted sum of components for each output channel of a pixel.  You can do the above which will convert every pixel into YIQ, **then** split it up into blocks.  I don't see what the problem is.

Comment: At this block of image there are others things that i want to compute , so i want to first separate the block and then do the calculations.Do you think that the numbers that are computed from this code are correct?

Comment: It seems to do what you want it to do, but again I find it very unnecessary.  You can again just do the conversion on the image itself, then split up the blocks accordingly. You can also achieve the interleaving of the pixels very easily by: `colorRGB = reshape(permute(ImageRGB, [3 1 2]), 3, []).';`, then do `YIQ = rgb2ntsc(colorRGB);`.  `colorRGB` will already be a `M x 3` matrix, so that column indexing you're doing is superfluous.  Also, with `permute` and `reshape`, it's unnecessary to have those sets of `for` loops to do what you want.

Comment: thank you very much for your time rayryeng.I am new to matlab so excuse me for my ignorance.thanks again.

Comment: @varmount no don't worry about it.  I wasn't referencing the fact that you are a new MATLAB user or that you are ignorant (you aren't btw).  I was just curious as to why you wanted to reshape your colour pixels into a 2D matrix from a 3D matrix.  BTW, if I have helped you, please consider accepting my answer :) Good luck!